# Why is $P(\limsup A_n)>0$ sufficient for $P(\limsup A_n)=1$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, limsup-and-liminf

Why for independent events, the necessary condition for $P(\limsup A_n)>0$ is sufficient for $P(\limsup A_n)=1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because, in full generality, $\limsup A_n$ belongs to the tail sigma-algebra generated by the sequence $(A_n)$ and because, in the present case, the sequence $(A_n)$ is independent hence, according to [Kolmogorov's zero-one law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov's_zero%E2%80%93one_law), the tail sigma-algebra is trivial in the sense that every event in it has probability $0$ or $1$.

Comment: Thanks so much! But I have not learnt tail sigma-algebra. Is this can be explained by Borel-Cantelli lemma? This is an exercise in that chapter. Thanks again!

Comment: Ah yes, this is quite trivial if one has the two Borel-Cantelli lemmas. The exercise must be meant to make you learn them...